# Group By, y crear nuevas columas para el resultado PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Tengo mi tabla **acceso**

*En esta tabla relaciono el Rol con un Modulo y el Permiso que tiene.*

[image: En esta tabla relaciono el Rol con un Modulo y el Permiso que tiene]

Lo que quiero es crear una vista que me devuelva los datos de la siguiente manera:

*Vista devolviendo los datos.*

[image: Vista devolviendo los datos]

Quiero agrupar por **Módulos** y devolver en 3 columnas nuevas 1 si tiene ese permiso o 0 si no lo tiene.

Intente hacerlo de esta manera pero **no me agrupa por modulos**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  modulo,
  case when permiso LIKE 'A' then 1 else 0 end AS p1,
  case when permiso LIKE 'C' then 1 else 0 end AS p2,
  case when permiso LIKE 'M' then 1 else 0 end AS p3
from acceso
group by modulo, permiso
```

**Agradezco su ayuda.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT modulo,
       MAX(case when permiso = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) AS p1,
       MAX(case when permiso = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) AS p2,
       MAX(case when permiso = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) AS p3
       from acceso
       group by modulo
```

Comentarios:

- La agrupación debe ser solo por módulo, por lo que los `CASE` deben estar dentro de un función de agregación.
- Si usas el `GROUP BY` tiene poco sentido usar el `DISTINCT`